# Is there any auto css property grouper in the world?

Tags: css

I need a tool to group all css classes and properties in a style sheet.
I searched a lot and couldn't find out.
for example there are two classes like this:

```
.one {
background: red;
display: none;
}
.two {
background: red;
display: block;
}
```

I want to have an output like this:

```
.one, .two {
background: red;
}
.one {
display: none;
}
.two {
display: block;
}
```

Is there any tool to do like this?!
I need it... really I need it.